# What EFB application do you recommend for commercial aviation?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone

I am looking for [Electronic Flight Bag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_flight_bag) applications running on smart phones or web. Optional functionalities: reporting, weight and balance, take-off, landing calculator, fuel and time-check calculator, document management. I need pros cons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ForeFlight for iOS is, in my opinion, the clear leader **if you aren't wedded to Jeppesen**. It's price competitive and I've been a happy user for almost 5 years now (!).

### pro

- outstanding UI
- same subscription works on multiple devices. Nearly all functionalist shared between iPad and iPhone.
- georeferenced approach and airport charts
- intuitive route planning with elevation profiles
- support for ADS-B weather and traffic
- support for pocket AHRS as backup PFD
- very slick W&B component
- documents library (FARs, etc)
- climb/cruise/descent performance calculations now integrated

### con

- iOS only
- charts are raster, not vector, making track-up orientation slightly harder to parse